# EACCES: permission denied when deploying node.js Web App through Microsoft Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, express, deployment

I'm deploying a node.js web app with Microsoft Azure. It is being deployed using the Azure extension in VS code. The app gets 'sucessfully deployed', however when you browse the website, the browser returns an *Application Error* message. This is the output of the console when I try to deploy the web app in question: `JA-6MP-Portfolio1`

```
13:00:39 JA-6MP-Portfolio1: Creating zip package...
13:00:55 JA-6MP-Portfolio1: Starting deployment...
13:01:55 JA-6MP-Portfolio1: Fetching changes.
13:01:55 JA-6MP-Portfolio1: Cleaning up temp folders from previous zip deployments and extracting pushed zip file /tmp/zipdeploy/d5e28b94-958e-4034-b2ea-6c19634eef06.zip (103.58 MB) to /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
13:02:11 JA-6MP-Portfolio1: Updating submodules.
13:02:11 JA-6MP-Portfolio1: Preparing deployment for commit id '14acc3bb56'.
13:02:11 JA-6MP-Portfolio1: Oryx-Build: Running kudu sync...
13:02:11 JA-6MP-Portfolio1: Command: kudusync -v 50 -f /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -t /home/site/wwwroot -n /home/site/deployments/14acc3bb566247a2bb30d0a4a3516cb8/manifest -p /home/site/deployments/dd3fd7cb1e5f47f0a2c10c4f5aa893bb/manifest -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;.deploy.sh"
13:02:14 JA-6MP-Portfolio1: Kudu sync from: '/tmp/zipdeploy/extracted' to: '/home/site/wwwroot'
13:02:14 JA-6MP-Portfolio1: Ignoring: .deployment
13:02:14 JA-6MP-Portfolio1: Ignoring: .git
13:02:14 JA-6MP-Portfolio1: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin'
13:02:14 JA-6MP-Portfolio1: \n/opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh kudusync -v 50 -f /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -t /home/site/wwwroot -n /home/site/deployments/14acc3bb566247a2bb30d0a4a3516cb8/manifest -p /home/site/deployments/dd3fd7cb1e5f47f0a2c10c4f5aa893bb/manifest -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;.deploy.sh"
13:02:14 JA-6MP-Portfolio1: App container will begin restart within 10 seconds.
13:02:23 JA-6MP-Portfolio1: Waiting for long running command to finish...
13:02:24: Deployment to "JA-6MP-Portfolio1" completed.
```

This web app was succesfully deployed 4 weeks prior. When I try to deploy the commit from 4 weeks ago, it no longer works. The `EACCES` error was not happening before.

Comment: Hey @Legatro, did you figure this out?